# Finding factors in an exponential function (over integers)

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

There are several ways to find factors of polynomials or to check that a term divides such a function, for example:

```
Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n > 1,
 Factor[n^3 - 1]]
```

(* (-1 + n) (1 + n + n^2) *)

or

```
PolynomialRemainder[n^3 - 1, n - 1, n] == 0
```

(* True *)

However, these approaches do not seem to work on this exponential function:

```
Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n > 1,
 Factor[n^(n - 1) - 1]]
```

(* $\frac{n^n-n}{n}$ *)

when in fact under these conditions there should be a factor of $(n-1)^2$.  Even checking the solution directly does not work:

```
PolynomialRemainder[n^(n - 1) - 1, (n - 1)^2, n] == 0
```

gives the error that `n^(n - 1) - 1` is not a polynomial.

***Edited (clarified) question***:

How to find the factors computationally given $n>1$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ of $f(n) = n^{n-1} - 1$?  Ideally, the output should be $(n-1)^2$ but assume we do not know that factor ahead of time.

***Alternate (but equivalent) question***:

Given $f(n) = n^{n-1} - 1$ *FOR ARBITRARY INTEGER* $n > 1$, show that we can ALWAYS write:

$$f(n) = (n-1)^2 g(n)$$

for $g(n)$ some function from integers to integers.  In this case we don't know or assume ahead of time that $(n-1)^2$ is a factor.  (In short, assuming and then *checking* that it is a factor does not count.)

*Example*:  If $n=5$, $n^{n-1}-1 = 624$, and $(n-1)^2 = 16$.  Indeed, $16$ divides $624$.

Same occurs for $n = 9098345098340598$.

*THAT* is what I want to "discover" computationally.

Comment: Is `Series[n^(n - 1) - 1, {n, 1, 3}]` sufficient? Or perhaps `AsymptoticEqual[(n - 1)^2, n^(n - 1) - 1, n -> 1]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll:  Thanks but no no no.  The factorization holds for arbitrary $n > 1$ and for the full series.  Special cases simply will not do here.

Comment: It's not a special case, why do you say it is?

Comment: Because you specify $n \to 1$.

Comment: But you do as well when you compute `PolynomialRemainder[n^3 - 1, n - 1, n]` don't you? Using `n -> 1` just specifies the expansion point, it doesn't mean that it only applies to `n == 1`.

Comment: No I don't.  Polynomial remainder says:  What is the remainder when I divide $n^3 -1$ by $n-1$ *FOR ARBITRARY n*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127590/discussion-between-carl-woll-and-david-g-stork).

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A060073 to this end.

Comment: @user64494:  Thanks... but I don't quite see the relevance of OEIS.  How would that help me computationally *find* the factor $n^{n-1} - 1$?  Specifically, how would I computationally find that $(n-1)^2$ was such a factor?

Comment: Somehow the alternate question seems incomplete: For all functions $F(n)$ defined for integers $n>1$, there exists a function $G(n)$ defined for integers $n>1$ such that $F(n)=(n-1)^2G(n)$ — on elementary algebraic grounds. Also $F(n) = (n+1)^3H(n)$ for some $H$, and so on.

Comment: I would say $n^{n-1}-1$ is a transcendental function, albeit an elementary one like $\sin \pi n$, and not particularly polynomial-like. While factoring is clearly defined in a polynomial ring, it perhaps deserves clarification from what domain factors may be taken and what conditions the complementary factors must satisfy. Is $(n+1)$ a factor of $\sin \pi n$? I'm assuming you do not mean integer factorization since the introductory task seeks "to find factors of polynomials," but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @Michael E2:  Good point.  Perhaps I misled folks by stating $n^{n-1} - 1$ was "polynomial-like."  You're right, it is exponential.  I'll fix that.  Thanks.

Comment: I think MSE is a right forum for such questions. This is math, not Mathematica.

Comment: @user64494:  I respectfully disagree.  `Factor[n^(n-1)-1]` "*should*" have worked (just as `Factor[x^3-1]` does) but doesn't because this not a polynomial.  How *in software* do you perform such a factorization?  Seems like it belongs on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the approach I recommended in the comments turned into a function:

```
factor[e_, n_ + p_, n_] := With[
    {a = Asymptotic[e, n -> -p, Assumptions -> n ∈ Reals]},

    (n+p)^Lookup[Rule @@@ FactorList[a], n+p, 0]
]
```

Some examples:

```
factor[n^3-1, n-1, n]
factor[n^(n-1)-1, n-1, n]
factor[(n^(n-1)-1)/(n+2), n+2, n]
```

> -1 + n

> (-1 + n)^2

> 1/(2 + n)

Another possibility for simple enough functions is to just use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
Solve[n^(n - 1) - 1 == 0, n, Reals]
```

> {{n -> -1}, {n -> 1}, {n -> 1}}

Since `{n -> 1}` is listed twice, this tells us that `(n - 1)^2` divides `n^(n-1) - 1`. Since `{n -> -1}` is listed once, this tells us that `(n + 1)` divides `n^(n-1) - 1`..

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but it does not answer the core problem.  Your contribution allows us to *check* that (here) $n-1$ is a factor of $f(n)=n^{n-1} -1$... in fact you show that $(n-1)^2$ divides $n^{n-1} - 1$.  (I only added that to demonstrate that $(n-1)^2$ so divided the $f(n)$.)  But what if you didn't *KNOW* what the factors of $f(n)$ were?  How would you find them in my $f(n)$?   Problem:  Again:  Given $f(n)$ find all factors of that function (for arbitrary $n>1$).  The goal would be to yield the factor $(n-1)^2$ always...  Just a bit different from *checking* it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You did say: "check that a term divides such a function"

Comment: You are correct.  But the "checking" was in the context of demonstrating to viewers that $(n-1)^2$ was *in fact* the desired output.  I've clarified the question.  But you see that your `Solve[n^(n-1) - 1 == 0]` doesn't address the problem.  Please note that a proper solution works for $n = 983459873495873459872345$... not just $n=1$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't know why you keep talking about explicit values of `n`. The Solve command shows that the roots are at -1 and 1, and the only question is what is the power of `n+1` and `n-1` in the factorization.

Comment: Another (equivalent) version of the question:  If $n >1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, show $n^{n-1} - 1$ is divisible by $(n-1)^2$.   Example ($n=5 \neq 1$):  Derive that $5^4 - 1 = 624$ is divisible by $(5-1)^2 = 16$.  (It is... quotient = $39$.)

Comment: Your statement "Since `{n -> 1}` is listed twice, this tells us that `(n - 1)^2` divides `n^(n-1) - 1`" is not grounded . In any case, `n^(n-1)-1==(n-1)^2*g[n]` does not imply `g[n]` takes integer values: think of `3==2*3/2`.